# Display correct cluster name in Prometheus Alertmanager messages to Slack

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, prometheus-alertmanager

I have installed the kube-prometheus stack on k8s via helm:

```
helm install prometheus prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack -n monitoring -f alertmanager-config.yaml
```

where the `alertmanager-config.yaml` looks as follows:

```
alertmanager:
  config:
    global:
      resolve_timeout: 5m
    route:
      group_wait: 20s
      group_interval: 4m
      repeat_interval: 4h
      receiver: 'null'
      routes:
      - receiver: 'slack-k8s-admin'
    receivers:
      - name: 'null'
      - name: 'slack-k8s-admin'
        slack_configs:
         - api_url: 'https://hooks.slack.com/services/...'
           channel: '#k8s-monitoring'
           send_resolved: true
           icon_url: https://avatars3.githubusercontent.com/u/3380462
           title: '[{{ .Status | toUpper }}{{ if eq .Status "firing" }}:{{ .Alerts.Firing | len }}{{ end }}] Monitoring Event Notification'
           text: >-
             {{ range .Alerts }}
               *Alert:* {{ .Annotations.summary }} - `{{ .Labels.severity }}`
               *Description:* {{ .Annotations.description }}
               *Graph:* <{{ .GeneratorURL }}|:chart_with_upwards_trend:> *Runbook:* <{{ .Annotations.runbook }}|:spiral_note_pad:>
               *Details:*
               {{ range .Labels.SortedPairs }} • *{{ .Name }}:* `{{ .Value }}`
               {{ end }}
             {{ end }}
```

I can receive the alerts after I configured them, however they never show me from which cluster they stem:

[image]

Since, I do have several clusters that should send to the same channel, it would be good to get notified which cluster has issues.

Do you know how I have to adapt the config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read the cluster name from Prometheus' labels as guided in the other answer.

Another option is to define a template for cluster name.

```yaml
    receivers:
    - name: 'slack-notifications'
      slack_configs:
      - channel: '#lolcats'
        send_resolved: true
        text: '{{ template "slack.default-alert.text" . }}'
    - name: 'null'
    templates:
    - '/etc/alertmanager/config/*.tmpl'
```

```yaml
  templateFiles:
    template_1.tmpl: |-
      {{ define "cluster" }}static-cluster-name{{ end }}

      {{ define "slack.default-alert.text" }}
      {{- $root := . -}}
        ... your template ...
        {{ template "cluster" $root }}
      {{ end }}
      {{ end }}
```

In place of a `static-cluster-name` text, you can use a placeholder from Helm if you're using the prometheus-stack helm chart:

```yaml
{{ define "cluster" }}{{ .ExternalURL | reReplaceAll ".*alertmanager\\.(.*)" "$1" }}{{ end }}
```

The latter will read the Helm value `.ExternalURL` defined earlier in the values.yaml. It's of course possible to also use a placeholder of whatever tool you're using to generate these manifests.

Answer (score 3):

You may add unique external labels to every cluster's kube-prometheus-stack config:

```
prometheus:
  prometheusSpec:
    externalLabels:
      cluster: prod
```

and your alerts will have these labels